# Simple Python Regex not matching

Tags: python, regex

Very simply, I am trying to replace a string that contains the substring XX.

```
import re

def replace_bogus(original, replacement):
    bogus = re.compile('[.]*[X][X][.]*')
    if bogus.match(original) != None:
        original = replacement

    return original

if __name__ == "__main__":
    teststr = replace_bogus('ABXX0123', '')
    print teststr
```

This code prints out ABXX0123.
Why is this regex wrong and what should I use instead?

Comment: `re` module have it's own `sub` method for replacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the dot (`.`) has no special meaning when it's inside a character class (i.e. `[.]`). The regex doesn't match the text and it returns `None`.

As has been said in the comments, the `re` module has its own method for replacing, i.e. the `sub` method. You can simply use it like so:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'XX')
result = re.sub(p, '', 'ABXX0123')
print result // => AB0123
```

Comment: Adding to that, I've put dots in characters classes because it can be clearer than backslash hell, but doing it for ```X``` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not state that you want to use regexp. What about:

```
teststr = 'ABXX0123'
print teststr.replace('XX', '')
```